# Javascript - firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged not firing upon login/logout

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I have the following code:

```
var config = {
       apiKey: "xxxxx",
       authDomain: "xxxxx",
       databaseURL: "xxxxx",
       projectId: "xxxxx",
       storageBucket: "xxxxx",
       messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

$("#loginButton").on('click', function(){
    logIn($("#email").val(), $("#pwd").val());
});

$("#logoutButton").on('click', function(){
   firebase.auth().signOut();
   console.log("clicked logout button");
});

function logIn(email, password){
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,    password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    alert(error.message);
  });
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("Signed in");                  
      firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        // ...
        console.log("Token = " + idToken);
        console.log("Logged in!");
        $("#loginButton").val(idToken);
        $("#loginForm").submit();
      }).catch(function(error) {
           // Handle error
           console.log(error);
      });
   }
   else{
       console.log("User signed out");
   }
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is: The user fills the email and password fields, click on a button with `id="loginButton"`, I sign in, get the token id and send it to server (Is this form hackish way of sending it recommended?) and verify the token id through the Admin SDK in my express app (Node.js).

The point is. The user does sign in and sign out (By refreshing the page I can see that "Signed in" and "User signed out" are printed).

**But why is `onAuthStateChanged` called only once when it should be observing/listening to every change on auth state?**

Why am I able to sign in and out but `onAuthStateChanged` is called only at the beginning (when page loads) and not called anymore upon button clicks (`loginButton` and `logoutButton`)?

Answer (score 3):

First, change `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken` to `user.getIdToken` in your auth state listener.

Second, you should add a then to signInWithEmailPassword promise and print some message to see if login succeed.

Last, auth state listener will not be triggered if you sign in the same user twice without log out in between. If you want to trigger some logic every time user logged in, you should put it into the then block of signInWithEmailPassword promise.

Comment: I followed your suggestions. It does indeed login and the `then( user =>` callback of the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method does return an user. The problem remains though. `AuthStateChanged` is only called at the beginning. So, If logout and reload the page the `AuthStateChanged` says I am logged out. When I login, `AuthStateChanged` does not fire. If I refresh the page again, `AuthStateChanged` says I am logged in, and if I click on the logout button, `AuthStateChanged` does not fire again. If I refresh the page again, it says I am logged out. Why is `AuthStateChanged` firing only once?

Comment: This should not happen. Can you deploy your page to somewhere so I can help you debug.

Comment: Sure Ti! I have deployed it. Do you only need the link or do you need some credentials?

Comment: The link and also the email password of a valid user so I can test your flow.

Comment: Do you have an e-mail that I can send to you?

Comment: tiwang0806@gmail.com

Comment: Is there any progress regarding this matter? I am facing pretty much the same problem in react-native app

Comment: Any news on this topic? I'm now facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question it seems like some people are still struggling with this.

I was having the same problem with onAuthStateChange not being fired on SignOut and I realized it was because I was unsubscribing from the listener before I signed out, so that by the time I signed out there was no listener anymore.